# Given a binary string , find all "legal"strings with more than consecutive 2 1's.

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

Given a binary string {${x_{1},x_{2},x_{3},...,x_{n}}$} find all "legal"  strings with more than $2$ consecutive ($ 1's)$.

For example for $N=7$ , we have $16$

With $3 (1's)$: {$1,1,1,0,0,0,0$} , {$0,1,1,1,0,0,0$} , {$0,0,1,1,1,0,0$} , {$0,0,0,1,1,1,0$} ,  {$0,0,0,0,1,1,1$}

With $4 (1's)$:
{$1,1,1,1,0,0,0$} , {$0,1,1,1,1,0,0$} , {$0,0,1,1,1,1,0$} ,{$0,0,0,1,1,1,1$}

With $5 (1's)$:
{$1,1,1,1,1,0,0$} , {$0,1,1,1,1,1,0$} ,{$0,0,1,1,1,1,1$}

With $6 (1's)$: {$1,1,1,1,1,1,0$} , {$0,1,1,1,1,1,1$} , {$1,1,1,0,1,1,1$}

With $7 (1's)$: {$1,1,1,1,1,1,1$}

Is there elegant way to calculate the number of such "legal "sub strings for any $N$.

$ Edit: $
A "legal" string is a string in which all consecutive $(1's)$ are with length $\geq 3$

Comment: You seem to be omitting cases.  For instance, the string $(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1)$ has three consecutive ones.

Comment: Sorry my bad , I meant if there are consecutive 1's all should be consecutive with length at least 3 .

Comment: {${1,1,1,0,1,1,1}$} is alright because it can be divided like {1,1,1} , {0} , {1,1,1}

Comment: I think it'll help if you include $0$($1$'s) in the count: $\{0,0,0,0,0,0,0\}$.

Comment: As a computer scientist, you can use binomial coefficient to calculate the number of permutations. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient

The algorithm is shortened to an easier name of  "n choose k"

Comment: The title talks of substrings but the question does not.  We are finding the number of strings.

Comment: Indeed , edited .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $B_n$ count the number of $n$-bit strings in which any $1$'s come in Bunches of $3$ or more. This is the count we want. Let $A_n$ count the number of $n$-bit strings which can *start* with an Arbitrary number of $1$'s, but as soon as a $0$ appears, any subsequent $1$'s occur in bunches of $3$ or more.  It's easy to see that $B_1=B_2=1$ and $B_3=2$, while $A_1=2$, $A_2=3$, and $A_3=4$.  What's important is the entangled recursion for $n\ge4$:

$$\begin{align}
A_n&=A_{n-1}+B_{n-1}\\
B_n&=B_{n-1}+A_{n-3}
\end{align}$$

That is, if the first digit of an $A$-type string is a $1$, the remaining $n-1$ digits are of $A$-type, while if the first digit is a $0$, the rest must be of $B$-type; likewise, if the first digit of a $B$-type string is a $0$, the remaining $n-1$ digits must be of $B$-type, while if the first digit is a $1$, then the next two must also be $1$'s, but the remaining $n-3$ digits can start with an arbitrary number of $1$'s, i.e., they are of $A$-type.

We can now compute

$$\begin{align}
A_4&=4+2=6\\
B_4&=2+2=4\\
\\
A_5&=6+4=10\\
B_5&=4+3=7\\
\\
A_6&=10+7=17\\
B_6&=7+4=11\\
\\
A_7&=17+11=28\\
B_7&=11+6=17
\end{align}$$

Note, $B_7=17$ agrees with what the OP found for $N=7$, provided you include the all-$0$ string $\{0,0,0,0,0,0,0\}$ in the count.

Comment: The recursion is nice and correct (+1), and check with sum provided in my answer.   It would be interesting to further develop the correspondence.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a binary string  with $s$ "$1$"'s and $m=n-s$ "$0$"'s in total. Let's put an additional (dummy) fixed $0$ at the start and at the end of the string.
We individuate as a *run* the consecutive $1$'s between two zeros, thereby including runs of null length.

[image: Bernoulli_Run_1]

With this scheme we have a fixed number of $m+1$ runs.
If we sequentially enumerate the length of each run so individuated, we construct a bijection with the number of [*weak* compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_%28combinatorics%29)
of $s$  into $m+1$ parts.

In your case we want that each part be either $0$ or greater than $2$, i.e.
$$
\eqalign{
  & N_s (s,m) =   \cr 
  &  = {\rm No}{\rm .}\,{\rm of}\,{\rm solutions}\,{\rm to}\;\left\{ \matrix{
  {\rm integer}\;x_{\,j}  \in \left\{ 0 \right\} \cup \left\{ {3,4, \cdots ,\left( s \right)} \right\} \hfill \cr 
  x_{\,1}  + x_{\,2}  + \; \cdots \; + x_{\,m + 1}  = s \hfill \cr}  \right.\quad  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,m + 1} {\left( \matrix{
  m + 1 \cr 
  k \cr}  \right){\rm No}{\rm .}\,{\rm of}\,{\rm solutions}\,{\rm to}\;\left\{ \matrix{
  {\rm integer}\;x_{\,j} \left\{ {3,4, \cdots ,\left( s \right)} \right\} \hfill \cr 
  x_{\,1}  + x_{\,2}  + \; \cdots \; + x_{\,k}  = s \hfill \cr}  \right.} \quad  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,m + 1} {\left( \matrix{
  m + 1 \cr 
  k \cr}  \right){\rm No}{\rm .}\,{\rm of}\,{\rm solutions}\,{\rm to}\;\left\{ \matrix{
  {\rm integer}\;y_{\,j} \left\{ {1,2, \cdots ,\left( {s - k} \right)} \right\} \hfill \cr 
  y_{\,1}  + y_{\,2}  + \; \cdots \; + y_{\,k}  = s - 2k \hfill \cr}  \right.} \quad  \cr} 
$$

The set in $y$ corresponds to the [(standard) compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_%28combinatorics%29) of $s-2k$ into $k$ parts, thus
$$
\eqalign{
  & N_s (s,m) = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,\min \left( {m + 1,\,s/3} \right)} {
 \binom{m+1}{k}
 \binom{s-1-2k}{k-1}
 }  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\,\left( { \le \,\min \left( {m + 1,\,s/3} \right)} \right)} {
 \binom{m+1}{m+1-k}
 \binom{s-1-2k}{s-3k}
}  \cr} 
$$

And the number you ask (also considering the null string) follows easily to be
$$
\eqalign{
  & N(n) = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,s\, \le \,n} {\;\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\,\left( { \le \,\min \left( {m + 1,\,s/3} \right)} \right)} {
 \binom{m+1}{m+1-k}   \binom{s-1-2k}{s-3k}
 } }  =  \quad \quad (1)  \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\,\left( { \le \,n/3} \right)} {\;\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,s\, \le \,n} {
 \binom{n+1-s}{n+1-k-s}   \binom{s-1-2k}{s-3k}
   }}  = \quad \quad (2)   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\,\left( { \le \,n/3} \right)} {\;\left( {\left( {\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,s\, \le \,n + 1} {
 \binom{n+1-s}{n+1-k-s}   \binom{s-1-2k}{s-3k}
  } } \right) - 
  \left( \matrix{0 \cr 0 - k \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{ n - 2k \cr n + 1 - 3k \cr}  \right)
  } \right)}  =   \quad \quad (3)  \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\,\left( { \le \,n/3} \right)} {\sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,s\,\left( { \le \,n + 1} \right)} {
 \binom{n+1-s}{n+1-k-s}   \binom{s-1-2k}{s-3k}
  } }  =   \quad \quad (4)  \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\,\left( { \le \,(n + 1)/4} \right)} {
\binom{n+1-2k}{n+1-4k} 
 }  \quad \quad (5)  \cr} 
$$
where:
 (2) : exchange summation order and replace $m$ with $n-s$;
 (3) : extend the summation in $s$ to the whole range and deducting the term $s=n+1$;
 (4) : the subtracted term is null everywhere;
 (5) : "double convolution".

> So finally
>   *the number of binary strings where the ones - if present - appears only in runs of three or more consecutive*
>   is given by the closed sum
>   $$
> N(n) = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\,\left( { \le \,(n + 1)/4} \right)} {
> \binom{n+1-2k}{n+1-4k} 
>  } 
> $$

Note that for $n=0,\cdots, 10$ we get for $N$
$$1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 7, 11, 17, 27, 44, 72$$
which checks with the answer by *Barry Cipra*, with
$$
B_{\,n}  = N(n)\quad A_{\,n}  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\,} {
\binom{n+1-2k}{n-4k}
  } 
$$